# I need to know if the gas fees can be paid after the transfer from an investment account to my cypto.com account

Tags: concurrency

I have a large amount to transfer from an investment account to my cypto.com account and can't pay the gas fees upfront. Is there any way to pay the gas fees out of the profit either before  the transfer or after? Please advise.